# If $\vert x \vert > 1$ then $x > 1$ or $x < –1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Prove that if $\vert x \vert > 1$ then $x > 1$ or $x < –1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I can't wrap my head around as to how it is provable, I could just put some values but that wouldn't be a concrete generalized proof

Comment: Do you know the definition of |x|?

Comment: I agree with the first comment, this is true by definition of the absolute value

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: No i didn't know the definition of abs(x), now i do through the answer given below, thank you

Comment: $|x|=\max(x,-x)$ also.

Comment: I think people should atleast know the definitions before posting a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since$$|x|=\begin{cases}x, &\text{ if } x\geq0\\-x, &\text{ if } x<0\end{cases},$$
so $|x|>1$ implies $x >1$ or $-x>1,$ i.e. $x>1$ or $x<-1.$

Comment: lul you wrote the definition

Comment: @justaguy That's all there was to do..

Comment: thank you, i didn't remember the definition of abs(x)

Comment: @AbdullahAnsari Recalling relevant definitions is the first step towards any proof.